# How do I turn this switch function into an array?

Tags: php, function, wpallimport

I have the following switch function on a website, however the data ($data) I now need to feed into it is a comma separated list i.e. AG,GCG,POA,CON,SPE

If AG is the first on the list it works, but the CSV string might not always be in the same order. There will always only be one of the below codes in the string, I want to extract this code and turn it into it's real name if it exists, how would I go about this? I believe I need an array, so the items of my array will be each item separated by a ","

```
<?php
function division($data)
{
    switch ($data){
        case 'AG':
            return 'Agricultural Machinery';
        case 'GCG':
            return 'Groundcare & Garden Machinery';
        case 'CON':
            return 'Construction Machinery';
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode

Comment: Use `explode()` to split it into an array, and `in_array()` to test if the string is in the array.

Comment: E.g. `if (in_array('AG', $data_array)) { return "Agricultural Machinery"; }`

Comment: How does `If AG is the first on the list it works` function? Are you already doing something with array and reading `0` index?

Comment: Example has `AG` and `GCG`. Is it intended that if `AG` is matched at all should return that or how do you determine which to return?

Comment: How do you call `division`?

Comment: So what do you want OUT of the function in each case

Comment: @user3783243 my example was exaggerated. Each CSV string will only contain one of AG, GCG or CON. I just need it translated when it finds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the comma-separated string into an array using the PHP `explode` function. Then you can loop through the array and check each item against your switch statement until you find a match. Once you have found a match, you can return the corresponding value.

```php
function division($data)
{
    $items = explode(',', $data);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        switch ($item){
            case 'AG':
                return 'Agricultural Machinery';
            case 'GCG':
                return 'Groundcare & Garden Machinery';
            case 'CON':
                return 'Construction Machinery';
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this code, the `$data` parameter is first split into an array using `explode(',', $data)`, which will split the string at every comma and return an array of the resulting values. Then, the `foreach` loop will iterate over each item in the array and check it against the `switch` statement. If a match is found, the corresponding value is returned. If no match is found, the function will return false.

Comment: Excellent example. Appreciated that works well. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan35 This would fail/be inaccurate when `not always be in the same order`. `GCG` being earlier would result in `Groundcare & Garden Machinery` being returned.

Comment: @user3783243 I understand. Luckily my query will only need to find one of the items in each string.

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, I would do something like this:

```
function division($data)
{
    $initials = [
        'AG' => 'Agricultural Machinery',
        'GCG' => 'Groundcare & Garden Machinery',
        'CON' => 'Construction Machinery'
    ];
    
    if(array_key_exists($data, $initials)) return $initials['data'];
    return false;

}
```